# Puppet Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Could not find declared class

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to deploy an application called Bag-Of-Holding via Puppet using the instruction as posted on github - https://github.com/ribeiroit/boh-puppet

I run the command: `sudo puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`
and I get the error below:

> Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Could not find declared class boh at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:2:2 on node lab1-hp-elitebook-8570p

It appears the puppet is having hard time finding the class `boh` which is already in the manifest folder

This is my directory tree:

```
/etc/puppet
├── code
├── manifests
└── modules
    └── boh-puppet
        ├── manifests
        └── templates
```

my `site.pp` file is located in `/etc/puppet/manifests`
and it looks like this:

```
node 'lab1-hp-elitebook-8570p' {
  class { 'boh':
    python_version   => 3,
    environment      => 'dev',
    language         => 'en',
    debug            => 'True',
    create_superuser => 'true',
    pkg_checksum     => '86b0164f7fd6c5e4aa43c8f056f08cea'
  }
}
```

And `init.pp` file has the `class {boh }` and that's located at: 
`/etc/puppet/modules/boh-puppet/manifests`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puppet requires certain namespace restrictions and conventions with module directory structure and class names when autoloading. In this case, your problem can be solved most simply and cleanly to follow normal conventions by renaming your module directory of `boh-puppet` to simply `boh`. That will fix your issue.

Consult the documentation here for more information: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/lang_namespaces.html

Since you are using `puppet apply` with absolute paths, you will also need to supply the path to your modules by modifying the command to: `sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`.

Comment: Matt, as per your suggestion, I went ahead and rename the boh-puppet to boh, but I still have the error message when I apply the site.pp file. This is how my directory tree looks like:

Comment: Matt, as per your suggestion, I went ahead and rename the boh-puppet to boh, but I still have the error message when I apply the site.pp file. This is how my directory tree looks like: /etc/puppet
├── code
├── manifests -----site.pp
└── modules
    └── boh
        ├── manifests --init.pp contain the defined class {boh} called  at site.pp
        └── templates      Error : ..Could not find declared class boh at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:2:2 on node lab1-hp-elitebook-8570p

Comment: @AdizaBaakoe Try changing the command to `sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`.

Comment: Well your input move me a step ahead (which is good news) and I thought I would let you know regardless even though I'm now confronted with new error message (posted below) and I will be spending sometime this afternoon digging through the line in the init.pp

Comment: Error ----  lab1@lab1-HP-EliteBook-8570p:/etc/puppet/modules$ sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
Warning: /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml: Use of 'hiera.yaml' version 3 is deprecated. It should be converted to version 5
   (in /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml)
Error: Evaluation Error: Resource type not found: CentOS at /etc/puppet/modules/boh/manifests/init.pp:37:9 on node lab1-hp-elitebook-8570p

Comment: @AdizaBaakoe Great. Please accept my answer (click the checkmark) as it answered your question. As for your followup question: it seems the module you are using has a bug in it. Feel free to open a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the module name properly. This should work:

```
node 'lab1-hp-elitebook-8570p' {
        class { 'boh-puppet':
        python_version => 3,
        environment => 'dev',
        language => 'en',
        debug => 'True',
        create_superuser => 'true',
        pkg_checksum => '86b0164f7fd6c5e4aa43c8f056f08cea'
        }
}
```

or the fqn this:

```
node 'lab1-hp-elitebook-8570p' {
        class { '::boh-puppet':
        python_version => 3,
        environment => 'dev',
        language => 'en',
        debug => 'True',
        create_superuser => 'true',
        pkg_checksum => '86b0164f7fd6c5e4aa43c8f056f08cea'
        }
}
```

Comment: As per your suggestion, I modified the site.pp file from  class { 'boh': to class { 'boh-puppet':  and  also class { '::boh-puppet': , none seems to resolve the problem. Error message received is  the same as previous : "Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Could not find declared class boh-puppet at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:2:2 on node lab1-hp-elitebook-8570p"

Comment: FYI, the defines class { boh is located in init.pp file at  /etc/puppet/modules/boh-puppet/manifests/init.pp whiles the site.pp file is located in the global manifets file /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp.  How do I accurately point the init.pp file in the site.pp file? I believe that my issue but I can't figure it out. It appear the defined class ( Class {'boh' : ) is not being seen when I launch the puppet apply command. Any advice would be appreciated. I'm running a masterless puppet.

Comment: The name of a class is given in its definition, independent of the directory in which the manifest containing that definition resides.  In order for Puppet to be able to *find* it, however, you generally need to name the directory to match the class's module.  The problem is indeed a mismatch there, but the correct solution is much more likely to be to change the directory name than to refer to the class by a different name.